# library not found for -lQt5Concurrent

Tags: macos, clang, qt5, osx-mavericks

I'm a complete newb when it comes to compiled languages, I'm a web developer. But I need to build a C++ library.

I'm using OSX 10.9 with homebrew. The library's dependancies are Qt5, openCV, openBR... I managed to get that all running. Installed Qt5.2 beta from the official page, I built openCV and openBR myself from sources.

Now this final application throws this, when I try to `make` it:

```
ld: library not found for -lQt5Concurrent
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libfacedet.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/facedet.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What the hell is `lQt5Concurrent`? There's no such lib installed on my system. I tried to find it, the only files that have `concurrent` in their name are header files in Qt's directory

`/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrent_global.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentcompilertest.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentexception.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentfilter.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentfilterkernel.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentiteratekernel.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentmap.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentmedian.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentreducekernel.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentrun.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentrunbase.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentthreadengine.h
/Users/ellmo/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtconcurrentversion.h`

I have no idea how to get the proper Qt5 devlibs and where to link them.
The author of the application in question cannot help me, as he has no experience with OSX. He said he built this with no problem on Ubuntu.

I also don't think I can show you much of the code, as the application is proprietary.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22998

In your .pro file, add:  `LIBS += -lQt5Concurrent`

There are a few other suggestions at that link as well, but I believe the one I mention is all I had to do.